# Python doesn't recognise Django app folder

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am new to Django and was following the tutorial here (https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/2017/09/04/a-complete-beginners-guide-to-django-part-1.html#hello-world) to get my first application running. I could not reference my application so I decided to name everything exactly as is in the tutorial in another Python project. I am unable to import view from boards no matter what I do (change it to *projectname.appname* and a number of different variations that I found on here). I have tried this tutorial on another computer I do not have access to at the moment and can confirm that it works usually. Is this an issue with PyCharm/my Python environment?

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqYPL.png)

[Error I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC6Op.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**
To resolve this I marked my ***Django Project Folder (not Python Project Folder)*** as root.